# Speeding up the type hierarchy popup in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, types, hierarchy

The type hierarchy popup (Ctrl-T) now sometimes takes five (5!) seconds to 'pop' up. Need I say more...

Is it possible for it to be set to only show a maximum number of items, or something. Breadth-first preferably. Or some other way to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more memory to your machine or configure more memory in your eclipse.ini settings. Eclipse builds a so called Java model to be able to answer your search requests, and that is typically quite fast, even for very large projects. So chances are high that in your case this is limited by the memory available to the JVM running Eclipse.

Comment: Good advice generally. I changed to -Xmx=1400m (and Xms=500m :). I _think_ it's better, at least the average time. A few invocations get me like {2s, 2s, 2.5s, 5s, 2s, 6s}. A rather unnatural usage pattern :) It does not seem to use more mem though; used VisualVM to peek inside. Used memory is below 100MB (Eclipse just opened, no real work done). Still the varying pop-up times. Would be interesting to see the index & query code; does it really build a two-way graph? Seems not to. Maybe I should try some different depth hierarchies, and see if the popup times grow proportionally with the depth.

Comment: Found an even slower/bigger type graph to try. The slow-motion effect helped me discern two phases: the search (progress bar moves), and the...'pop': nothing moves, while the GUI tree component presumably prepares to render. Both are way too slow with larger type graphs. So this probably can't really be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sort-of-solution: use "Find References" (Ctrl-G). Much faster, at least for me right now.

Drawback 1: Not quite so handy, you need to unfold package entries to get to the classes and things. And so you don't see the class name directly.

Drawback 2: It only shows one 'hop' away though. (Which is probably a contributing factor to being faster.)